# How to process Write-Information pipeline output when using SilentlyContinue

Tags: powershell, stream, pipeline

`Write-Information` seems to output unwanted records down the pipeline when `$InformationPreference` is `SilentlyContinue`.  Particularly since the default is `SilentlyContinue`, I would expect this to be a problem.

```
function foo {
    $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    Write-Verbose "verbose silent"

    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
    Write-Verbose "verbose continue"

    $InformationPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    Write-Information "info silent"

    $InformationPreference = 'Continue'
    Write-Information "info continue"
}

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
# 5.1.15063.1805

foo
# VERBOSE: verbose continue
# info continue

foo *>&1 | % { "redirected: $_" }
# redirected: verbose continue
# redirected: info silent
# redirected: info continue
```

As expected, a `$VerbosePreference` of `SilentlyContinue` causes `Write-Verbose` to not produce a message, so there is no message to redirect.

Also as expected, an `$InformationPreference` of `SilentlyContinue` correctly displays nothing on the console, HOWEVER a message is redirected down the pipeline.

This seems wrong, since once the message is in the pipline, how can a consumer determine whether that Information message should be silently discarded?

Is the pipelining of InformationRecords broken, or how can I correctly filter out unwanted InformationRecords as a pipeline consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intriguing. However, there is a workaround based on the following statement from *[About CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1#informationaction)* help topic:

> `-InformationAction:Ignore` suppresses the informational message and
>   continues running the command. Unlike *`SilentlyContinue`*,
>   ***`Ignore`* completely forgets the informational message**; it doesn't add the informational message to the information stream.

In the following script, I made a few alterations:

1. Setting a function output to a variable (of course, you can pass in into a pipeline instead; see the last script line `Debug-InfoAction *>&1 | ForEach-Object {"redirected: $_"}` and its result).
2. `InformationAction` parameter (unfortunately, **the value *`Ignore`* is not supported for an *`ActionPreference`* variable**; hence, this adjustment becomes a **crucial point** of the solution).

> The `InformationAction` parameter overrides, but does not replace the
>   value of the `$InformationAction` preference variable when the
>   parameter is used in a command to run a script or function.

**The script**:

```
function Debug-InfoAction {
    param(
        [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]
        $InfoAction='Ignore'
    )
    Write-Verbose     "verbose…………$InfoAction" -Verbose
    Write-Information "InfoAction=$InfoAction" -InformationAction $InfoAction
}

foreach ( $InfoAction in @(
                'SilentlyContinue',
                'Continue', 
                'Ignore'
            ) # exclude from testing: 'Stop', 'Inquire', 'Suspend'
         ) {
    $aux = ''
    $aux = Debug-InfoAction -InfoAction $InfoAction 6>&1
    '{0,16}:{1}' -f $InfoAction, $aux
}
# check newly defined default InformationAction
    $InfoAction = 'Default' 
    $aux = ''
    $aux = Debug-InfoAction                         6>&1
    '{0,16}:{1}' -f $InfoAction, $aux
    Debug-InfoAction *>&1 | ForEach-Object { "redirected: $_" }
```

**Output**:

```
D:\PShell\SO\57303102a.ps1
```

> ```
> VERBOSE: verbose…………SilentlyContinue
> SilentlyContinue:InfoAction=SilentlyContinue
> VERBOSE: verbose…………Continue
>         Continue:InfoAction=Continue
> VERBOSE: verbose…………Ignore
>           Ignore:
> VERBOSE: verbose…………Ignore
>          Default:
> redirected: verbose…………Ignore
> ```

---

### Edit.

> Unfortunately it doesn't really help the core problem that *if my
>   function is calling someone elses code* that uses `Write-Information`
>   then when my code redirects (or captures) the *Information* stream,
>   then I have no way of discarding Information that was written with
>   `SilentlyContinue`.

The latter eligible remonstrance shows *my* insufficiency…  Let's have the following simple captures:

```
$c = Write-Information "Continue" -InformationAction Continue         6>&1
$s = Write-Information "Silently" -InformationAction SilentlyContinue 6>&1
```

Both are of `[System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord]` type. I tried to find a difference (even in their *subproperties*) but was unable to, except those in the data themself:

```
param(
  [switch]$IncludeEqual = $false
)
begin {
  Function Compare-Property {
    param(
        $RefObject, 
        $DifObject,
        [switch]$IncludeEqual
    )
    # compare objects
    Compare-Object $RefObject $DifObject -IncludeEqual | 
      Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                     @{N='objects';E={'Function Compare-Property'}},
                     InputObject
    Write-Verbose $RefObject.GetType().FullName -Verbose:$IncludeEqual

    # a level down: compare properties of objects individually

    $cpe = $RefObject.PsObject.Properties.GetEnumerator()
    $spe = $DifObject.PsObject.Properties.GetEnumerator()
    While ( $cpe.MoveNext() -and $spe.MoveNext() ) {
      Compare-Object $cpe.Current.Value `
                     $spe.Current.Value -IncludeEqual:$IncludeEqual |
        Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                       @{N='objects';E={$spe.Current.Name}}, 
                       InputObject

        # more level down: 
        # compare properties of properties of objects individually

        $cpeIn = $cpe.Current.PsObject.Properties.GetEnumerator()
        $speIn = $spe.Current.PsObject.Properties.GetEnumerator()
        While ( $cpeIn.MoveNext() -and $speIn.MoveNext() ) {
          Compare-Object $cpeIn.Current.Value `
                         $speIn.Current.Value -IncludeEqual:$IncludeEqual |
            Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                           @{N='objects';
                             E={ $cpe.Current.Name + '.' + $cpeIn.Current.Name}},
                           InputObject
        }      
    }
  }
  $c = Write-Information "Continue" -InformationAction Continue         6>&1
  $s = Write-Information "Silently" -InformationAction SilentlyContinue 6>&1
}
process {
  Compare-Object $c.GetType() $s.GetType() -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                   @{N='objects';E={'.GetType()'}}, InputObject
  Compare-Object $c.PsObject.TypeNames `
                 $s.PsObject.TypeNames -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                   @{N='objects';E={'.PsObject.TypeNames'}}, 
                   InputObject
  Compare-Object ($c | Get-Member -MemberType Properties -Force).PsTypeNames `
                 ($s | Get-Member -MemberType Properties -Force).PsTypeNames `
                  -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                   @{N='objects';E={'(gm).PsTypeNames'}}, 
                   InputObject
  Compare-Object $c $s -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -Property SideIndicator, 
                   @{N='objects';E={"$($c.GetType().Name) itself"}},
                   InputObject

  Compare-Property  -RefObject $c `
                    -DifObject $s          -IncludeEqual:$IncludeEqual

  Compare-Property  -RefObject $c.PsObject `
                    -DifObject $s.PsObject -IncludeEqual:$IncludeEqual
}
```

**Output**:

```
D:\PShell\SO\57303102c.ps1
```

> ```
> SideIndicator objects                   InputObject
> ------------- -------                   -----------
> ==            .GetType()                System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord
> ==            .PsObject.TypeNames       System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord
> ==            .PsObject.TypeNames       System.Object
> ==            (gm).PsTypeNames          System.Object[]                        
> ==            (gm).PsTypeNames          System.Array                           
> ==            (gm).PsTypeNames          System.Object                          
> =>            InformationRecord itself  Silently
> <=            InformationRecord itself  Continue
> =>            Function Compare-Property Silently
> <=            Function Compare-Property Continue
> =>            MessageData               Silently
> <=            MessageData               Continue
> =>            MessageData.Value         Silently
> <=            MessageData.Value         Continue
> ==            Function Compare-Property psobject {Members, Properties, Methods, Imme...
> =>            ImmediateBaseObject       Silently
> <=            ImmediateBaseObject       Continue
> =>            ImmediateBaseObject.Value Silently
> <=            ImmediateBaseObject.Value Continue
> =>            BaseObject                Silently
> <=            BaseObject                Continue
> =>            BaseObject.Value          Silently
> <=            BaseObject.Value          Continue
> ```

Comment: That is good extra info that explains an important difference between Ignore and SilentlyContinue.  Unfortunately it doesn't really help the core problem that if my function is calling someone elses code that uses `Write-Information` then when my code redirects (or captures) the Information stream, then I have no way of discarding Information that was written with SilentlyContinue.

Comment: Thanks for the extra edit comparing the two records. I accept your answer although it unfortunately concludes that what I want cannot be achieved. I must say I think the Powershell stream design seems quite a mess of inconsistencies.